# How to ignore rewriteCondition for 1 file with parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've looked at other suggestions on stack overflow questions and tried them however cannot get it to work...

**Case**

I am upgrading to from `mywebsite.com` to `app.mywebsite.com` and want to redirect all visits on `app.mywebsite.com` to `index.html` (spa) except for a script I need to run when visitors come from the `mywebsite.com` which is located in `app.mywebsite.com/upgrader.php`

**Example .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

# Ignore existing files or upgrader.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/upgrader\.php$ <--- not working
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Redirect all other requests
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

**Question**

How can I add a condition where if the url is `app.mywebsite.com/upgrader.php` that it goes to that `upgrader.php` file in stead of the `index.html`?

Comment: What is the apache version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Ignore existing files or upgrader.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/upgrader\.php$
RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

This will use somewhat opposite logic from yours: it will run RewriteRule only in case all 3 conditions are satisfied: file is **not** requested, folder is **not** requested, upgrader is **not** requested (note the exclamation mark in Rewrite Conditions!)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this but could you point out what the difference is with what I created?

Comment: Thank you :) is it also possible to rewrite without the extension? If so is it just doing `!^/upgrader$`?

Comment: `!` is apache negation, the rest is just a regex (you can play around and see what happens https://regex101.com/r/FS8wg9/1)